# Conky new text overlap with an old text

Tags: conky

My problem is best to be describe using picture :

Edit 1 : Here is the link to the picture, https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWEmQ.png

As you can see in `Process Name` and and my wifi infos, the text will overlap after conky is running for about 5 minutes. I tried to run conky using `--double-buffer` argument but got no luck.

Here is my conky's script :

```
#========================================================================
# Conky-Serdar
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#taken from http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Conky-color?content=153230
#
#sudo apt-get install conky
#extract the zip file and move files to .conky in your home folder
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#Run(Terminal): 
# conky -c ~/.conky/conkyrc
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#Autostart(Openbox):
# sudo leafpad .config/openbox/autostart
#add these lines below for autostart (without first #)
# # System Info
# conky -c ~/.conky/conkyrc &
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#Autostart(Ubuntu/Gnome): create conky-startup.sh paste below (without first #)
# #!/bin/bash
# conky -c ~/.conky/conkyrc ;
#alt+F2 type gnome-session-properties add line below to your startup section
# .conky/conky-startup.sh
#
#   Gnome 14 and later
#
#   cp ~/.conky/conky.desktop /usr/share/gnome/autostart/
#
#   or
#
#   gedit /usr/share/gnome/autostart/conky.desktop
#   addlines below;
#
##  #conky.desktop
##  [Desktop Entry]
##  Type=Application
##  Name=Conky
##  Comment=Start conky script
##  Exec=.conky/conky-startup.sh
##  OnlyShowIn=GNOME;
##  X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Application
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#Autostart(LXDE)
# sudo leafpad  /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
#add (without first #)
# @conky -c ~/.conky/conkyrc
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Disable a section, add "#" beginning of the line
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# For quad/dual core processors add/remove "#" beginning of the core2,3,4
#
# CPU Info: cat /proc/cpuinfo
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Battery Info: ls /proc/acpi/battery > cat /proc/acpi/battery/****/info
# For battery info add/remove "#" beginning of the battery line
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# alignment b=bottom t=top l=left r=right
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Nvidia gpu temp: apt-get install nvidia-settings
#
#========================================================================

background yes
update_interval 1
total_run_times 0

cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2
temperature_unit celsius

double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes
text_buffer_size 2048

gap_x 05
gap_y 40
minimum_size 190 325
maximum_width 325
own_window yes
own_window_type override
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
alignment tr

draw_shades yes
draw_outline yes
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders yes

override_utf8_locale yes
use_xft yes
xftfont caviar dreams:size=8
xftalpha 0.5
uppercase no

default_color DeepSkyBlue
color1 Orange
color2 Green
color3 Red
color4 Yellow
color5 DDDDDD
color6 AAAAAA
color7 888888
color8 666666

TEXT

${color1}${font :Bold:size=14} $alignc ${time %H}:${time %M}
${color}${font :Bold:size=14} $alignc ${time %h} ${time %e} - ${time %Y}${font :Bold:size=08} 
$alignc(${time %A})
${color8}$alignc Uptime: $uptime
${color8}${hr 2} 
${color8}$alignc ${pre_exec lsb_release -d | cut -f 2| tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"}${color8}$alignc $sysname $kernel
${color8}$alignc ${execi 1000 cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | sed -e 's/model name.*: //'| uniq}
${color8}${hr 2}
${color4}CPU $alignr${color6}CPU: ${color1}${hwmon 0 temp 1}°C ${color6}GPU: ${color1}${execi 60 nvidia-settings -t -q GPUCoreTemp}°C 
${color}${cpubar 8,325}:${color5}$cpu%
${color7}Core1: ${color}${cpubar cpu1 7,80} ${color7}${cpu cpu1}% $alignr${color7}${cpu cpu2}%${color}${cpubar cpu2 7,80}${color7} :Core2
${color7}Core3: ${color}${cpubar cpu3 7,80} ${color7}${cpu cpu3}% $alignr${color7}${cpu cpu4}%${color}${cpubar cpu4 7,80}${color7} :Core4
${color}${cpugraph 15,}
${color5}Process Name ${color5}$alignr CPU% MEM%
${color6}${top name 1}$alignr${top cpu 1}   ${top mem 1}
${color7}${top name 2}$alignr${top cpu 2}   ${top mem 2}
${color8}${top name 3}$alignr${top cpu 3}   ${top mem 3}
${color8}${top name 4}$alignr${top cpu 4}   ${top mem 4}

${color4}Memory
${color6}RAM : ${color5}($memmax)${alignr}${color6}$mem${color}${membar 8,75}
${color6}SWAP: ${color5}($swapmax)${alignr}${color6}$swap${color}${swapbar 8,75}

${color8}${hr 4}

${color4}HDD
${color5}Linux:${color1}(${fs_type})${alignr}${color7}${fs_used /}  <  >  ${color7}${fs_free /}
${color8}Total: ${fs_size /}${alignr}${color}${fs_bar 8,150}

${color5}Windows:${color1}(${fs_type /run/media/Windows})${alignr}${color7}${fs_used /run/media/Windows}  <  >  ${color7}${fs_free /run/media/Windows}
${color8}Total: ${fs_size /run/media/Windows}${alignr}${color}${fs_bar 8,150 /run/media/Windows}

${color5}Extra:${color1}(${fs_type /run/media/Extra})${alignr}${color7}${fs_used /run/media/Extra}  <  >  ${color7}${fs_free /run/media/Extra}
${color8}Total: ${fs_size /run/media/Extra}${alignr}${color}${fs_bar 8,150 /run/media/Extra}

${color7}HDD Read-> ${alignc}${color2}${diskio_read}/s ${alignr}${color3}${diskio_write}/s ${color7}<-HDD Write
${color2}${diskiograph_read 8,150} ${alignr}${color3}${diskiograph_write 8,150}${color}

${color8}${hr 4}

${color4}Lan${color} ${alignr}${color7}IP: ${addr eth0}
${color7}Download: ${color2}${downspeed eth0} k/s ${alignr} $alignr${color7}Upload: ${color3} ${upspeed eth0} k/s
${color2}${downspeedgraph eth0 8,150} ${alignr}${color3}${upspeedgraph eth0 8,150}
${color7}Total:${color2}${totaldown eth0} ${alignr}${color7}Total:${color3}${totalup eth0}

${color4}Wifi${alignr}${color7}IP: ${addr wlan0}
${color7}ESSID:${color1}${wireless_essid wlan0} ${color7}Rate:${color1}${wireless_bitrate wlan0} ${alignr}${color7}Quality:${color1}${wireless_link_qual_perc wlan0}%${color}${wireless_link_bar 8,75 wlan0}
${color7}Download: ${color2}${downspeed wlan0}KB/s ${color3} $alignr${color7}Upload: ${alignr}${color3}${upspeed wlan0}KB/s
${color2}${downspeedgraph wlan0 8,150} ${alignr}${color3}${upspeedgraph wlan0 8,150}
${color7}Total:${color2}${totaldown wlan0} ${alignr}${color7}Total:${color3}${totalup wlan0}

${color8}${hr 4}

${color4}Battery${color1}${alignr}${battery_percent BAT1}
${color}${battery_bar BAT1  8,}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a line break in following part

```
${color7}ESSID:${color1}${wireless_essid wlan0} ${color7}Rate:${color1}${wireless_bitrate wlan0} ${alignr}${color7}Quality:${color1}${wireless_link_qual_perc wlan0}%${color}${wireless_link_bar 8,75 wlan0}
```

could solve your problem?

Comment: What did you mean by line break? Can you show me the example?